# moving components at design time in VCL delphi at end-user designing

Tags: vcl, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Ok so I am currently creating an program which is based on vcl. User will be adding removing resize move labels images memos etc. in vcl how can user move resize increase decrease heights width smoothly in components at end-user designing?
Should I use external package's or I can do that in-built ?

Comment: What do you mean? Obviously, the [designer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yp_HvTlEiTA) allows you to move and resize controls visually

Comment: Please show some of your efforts.

Comment: @ExDev I mean I am creating a form which is basically a desinger for my software on which user will create edit modify label edit memo images etc. So the question is how all this process can be done for end user designing of my base is vcl in Delphi? FMX can that but for vcl what can we use ?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think there's a built-in functionality like that in VCL

Comment: I suggest you to check the [Layout Control from DevExpress](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odYs4zfiZwM)

Comment: How can I use the label edit check box and radio buttons in my program how to include them and how to include effects such as glow blur shadow etc to apply on the mentioned components ? At end-user-design ? So user can easily put an label and apply such effect and then move resize them that's what I am trying to say .